# Deploy azure webjob in "stop" mode

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-deployment

I'm deploying Webjob with automate deployment in Azure portal in staging slot, but the problem is this webjob is running directly after deployment and it might cause a confusion between the main slot webjob and the staging one.

Is there a way to deploy the webjob without running it unless I start it and swap slots?

Comment: Very important feature. We are also looking forward to find that information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Azure WebJob from starting up after publishing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513448/how-to-prevent-azure-webjob-from-starting-up-after-publishing)