# Ensure Azure WebJob automatically starts during VIP swap to Production

Tags: azure, swap, azure-webjobs

I want to ensure my Azure WebJob is started by default when I swap between staging and production. Basically I want to avoid swapping my staging Website and having a stopped WebJob finding it's way into production.

I'm aware of applying `WEBJOBS_STOPPED = 1` to my staging's app setting (using a sticky slot setup), however I want to ensure the opposite is true for production.

Is there an app setting I can apply?

Comment: Need confirmed with you: would you like to automatically start your Webjob into production enviroment after you swaped your slots?

Comment: Yes. It's stopped in staging, then when I VIP swap to production I'd like it to automatically start.

Comment: Would you like to separate the site and webjob if it is necessary? Currently, Azure support the Azure Webjob standalone which doesn't depend on site.   Also, you can use the disable.job to control your webjob. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24537152/4836342

Comment: Seems like what you are asking for is the default behavior of the active slot. See if this [SO Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513448/how-to-prevent-azure-webjob-from-starting-up-after-publishing#24537152) describes what you are looking for.

Comment: You're right, it's the default behaviour. Just wasn't documented very clearly at the time I wrote this question.